# why cast as date in insert-select does not work the same way as select-only?

Tags: mysql

Why does cast as date work on SELECT, but not when this select is used within an insert?

A column of type varchar contains dates as string, but other strings as well.
I would like to cast the string into a date if it is a date. Else it can be just null.

```
Sample data:
'2022-10-14' -> date
'1.1.2021' -> date
'01.05.2018' -> date
'as soon as possible' -> null
'start' -> null
NULL -> null
'2015-02-30' -> date
```

and so on

So there are several data-types. This is why I cannot simply use STR_TO_DATE.

On SELECT simply using cast as date does a great job.
But when using this SELECT as INSERT it seems to be ignored.
I need to fix that somehow. Thanks for any ideas.

You can reproduce the behavior with this SQL:

```
drop table if exists source_table;
drop table if exists date_table;

create table source_table(
    string_date_col varchar(255) null
);

create table date_table(
    date_col date null
);

insert into source_table (string_date_col) values ('1.1.23'); -- -> date
insert into source_table (string_date_col) values ('31.12.2021'); --> date
insert into source_table (string_date_col) values (null); --> null
insert into source_table (string_date_col) values ('start'); --> null

-- works just fine
-- gives either a valid date or null else
select cast(string_date_col as date) from source_table
;

-- SQL-Error [1292] [22001]: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'start'
insert into date_table (date_col)
select cast(string_date_col as date) from source_table
;
```

Comment: So you want e.g. 01.05.2018 to be null?

Comment: Do you have things that look like dates but aren't?  E.g. 2015-02-30

Comment: SELECT does not alter the data. If the value cannot be trearted as DATE value then SELECT returns NULL and produces warning. Rather than INSERT which alters the data - it produces an error in strict mode (investigate current SQL Mode). You may use INSERT IGNORE.

Comment: I agree you should just use INSERT IGNORE. You could try to check if it's a date on your own, but I don't think there will be any advantage of this.

Comment: '1.1.23' - tricky is that dmy,ymd,mdy,dym...

Comment: i added some expectations behind my testdata. 2015-02-30 should also be a date

Comment: Insert ignore is not desired I need the row but with null instead. I also tried case when but how do i test if it is a date? 'case when cast(mydate as date) is not null then...' leads to the same error. How can i safely test it for being a date?

Comment: @Akina if I understand you right using cast on a non-date value returns a warning and after the warning it results to null-value. In the insert it would also result into null value but before it can result it, it raises an error. So the error is not about trying to insert an invalid value but about casting an invalid value?

Comment: even using a view to do the cast and select it within the insert leads to the same error

Comment: I do not see the difference. There is an action (INSERT) and there is its effect (error raised, none inserted). Of course you're right - it is CAST which produces an error, you may ensure this by defining the destination column as non-nullable which won't result in error reason/message change.

Comment: but i want the destination be null when values are not dates

Comment: for me it seems that mysql is not able to do what I want. I am thinking now of creating a function to call which checks for regex with a pre-defined set of valid date formats I want to support. Since I do not fully know all data I may miss something this way.

Comment: btw. since the question was why it happens you already answered that, may create an answer to get the tick. the questions about how to solve it may remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Akina for the explanation
Im writing this as answer for better visibility

As Akina said on SELECT the cast produces a warning which is ignored so far and the CAST is done more or less correctly.
The warning can be seen in the log.

When doing an INSERT the warning becomes an error (due to the fact that its an insert and not a select any more). Due to the error the process aborts.